# Algorithm finding two parallel planes enclosing a set of points

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm working on the implementation of an algorithm used to determine the safest point for a drone to land, using this [paper](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvtol.org%2F05AC4680-E91B-11E0-8A940050568D0042&ei=jfoFUar9I9Cz0QW18YCgAw&usg=AFQjCNGN0LrE1KAE-V_xg9up320zygRlkQ&bvm=bv.41524429,d.d2k).

To do so I'm tring to find two parallel planes enclosing a set of 9 points while minimizing the distance r between those two planes.

r will then represent the roughness of the terrain.

I would like a general strategy to solve the problem or a link to a paper describing a solution.

Comment: This paper:- https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEoQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.78.229%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=APwFUfWNKcH-iwL-94CoBA&usg=AFQjCNGuQ4WRAu1WJQ6F6Fdvubhr0R2vkw&bvm=bv.41524429,d.cGE&cad=rja might be of use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to find planes normal. Then building the planes is easy.

And there is finite number of candidates for plane normal: cross-products of edge vectors of convex hull (this includes but is not limited to face normals). For this number of points you can just count them all.

Why?

- Every plane touches some non-zero number of points (otherwise it can be moved closer).
- If we can rotate planes even slightly without losing connection with these points, distance will decrease.
- So the optimum planes can not rotate.
- If a plane touches two points, it can rotate only around this edge.
- A plane cannot rotate if it touches two non-parallel edges.
- Then its normal is cross-product of those edge vectors.

Answer (score 3):

Can you do the following:

1. Find the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the 9 points
2. For each plane `p` in the convex hull, find the point `pt` not in `p` that is the farthest away, let the second plane be that which is parallel to `p` and passes through `pt` and compute the distance
3. Take the minimum

Comment: Surely `pt` would need to be chosen to be the furthest point from `p` otherwise the parallel plane through `pt` wouldn't be beyond all the other points and thus the pair of planes wouldn't enclose them all.

Comment: Better, and it seems like this gives a great answer nearly always.  Here's one case where it doesn't: a hull (-10,0,0)(+10,0,0)(0,10,1),(0,-10,1).  This can be bound by two planes 1 unit apart (z=0 and z=1) but which has no face coplanar with either plane in that situation.  Hmmm ... interesting problem.

Comment: @IanMercer Yes, I tried to prove that the above algorithm is correct, but there are two possibilities: in all cases 4 points are in the planes, but it's either 3 and 1 or 2 and 2. It's only correct in the 3 and 1 situation.